# Preventing a Function from Modifying a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a code where I try to keep the original list of unprinted designs for the records:

```
def print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_models):
    """
    Simulate printing each design, until none are left.
    Move each design to completed_models after printing.
    """
    while unprinted_designs:
        current_design = unprinted_designs.pop()
        # Simulate creating a 3D print from the design.
        print("Printing model: " + current_design)
        completed_models.append(current_design)
def show_completed_models(completed_models):
    """Show all the models that were printed."""
    print("\nThe following models have been printed:")
    for completed_model in completed_models:
        print(completed_model)
unprinted_designs = ['iphone case', 'robot pendant', 'dodecahedron']
completed_models = []
print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_models)
show_completed_models(completed_models)
```

The output of it is:

```
Printing model: dodecahedron
Printing model: robot pendant
Printing model: iphone case

The following models have been printed:
dodecahedron
robot pendant
iphone case
```

The desired output is:

```
Printing model: iphone case
Printing model: robot pendant
Printing model: dodecahedron

The following models have been printed:
iphone case
robot pendant
dodecahedron
```

I tried two methods, one with the **slice notation [:]** and one with **copy module**

1 option. The slice notation [:] makes a copy of the list to send to the function. The function print_models() can do its work because it still receives the
names of all unprinted designs. But this time it uses a copy of the original
unprinted designs list, not the actual unprinted_designs list. The list
completed_models will fill up with the names of printed models like it did
before, but the original list of unprinted designs should stay unaffected by the
function. But it doesn't:

```
def print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_models):
    """
    Simulate printing each design, until none are left.
    Move each design to completed_models after printing.
    """
    while unprinted_designs:
        current_design = unprinted_designs.pop()
        # Simulate creating a 3D print from the design.
        print("Printing model: " + current_design)
        completed_models.append(current_design)
def show_completed_models(completed_models):
    """Show all the models that were printed."""
    print("\nThe following models have been printed:")
    for completed_model in completed_models:
        print(completed_model)
unprinted_designs = ['iphone case', 'robot pendant', 'dodecahedron']
completed_models = []
print_models(unprinted_designs[:], completed_models)
show_completed_models(completed_models)
```

2 option:

```
import copy
def print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_models):
    """
    Simulate printing each design, until none are left.
    Move each design to completed_models after printing.
    """
    while unprinted_designs:
        current_design = unprinted_designs.pop()
        # Simulate creating a 3D print from the design.
        print("Printing model: " + current_design)
        completed_models.append(current_design)
def show_completed_models(completed_models):
    """Show all the models that were printed."""
    print("\nThe following models have been printed:")
    for completed_model in completed_models:
        print(completed_model)
unprinted_designs = ['iphone case', 'robot pendant', 'dodecahedron']
completed_models = []
print_models(copy.deepcopy(unprinted_designs), completed_models)
show_completed_models(completed_models)
```

But none of them gives me the desired output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `pop` at all? Just iterate over the list with `for current_design in unprinted_designs:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
current_design = unprinted_designs.pop()
```

to

```
current_design = unprinted_designs.pop(0)
```

Essentially you want to pop from the index position zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem assertion is wrong.  Add this statement at the bottom of `1 option`:

```
print(unprinted_designs)
```

Output:

```
['iphone case', 'robot pendant', 'dodecahedron']
```

This shows that the original list *is* intact.  Your output is reversed exactly as your `print` tracing shows: you traverse the copied list in reverse order.  This reversal should not surprise you, since you've gone to extra trouble to reverse the copied list and to empty it, one element at a time (I'm not sure why you did that).

If you really *do* want the items in order, without altering the original list, then use the tools Python provides:

```
for current_design in unprinted_designs:
    print("Printing model: " + current_design)
    completed_models.append(current_design)
```